# How do I overwrite a task in gradle kotlin-dsl

Tags: gradle, task, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In Groovy, I overwrite a task like this:

```
task jar(overwrite: true) {
    ...
}
```

How do I do that with Kotlin-dsl? I know that I can create a task like this:

```
tasks {
     val jar by creating {
          ...
     }
}
```

but I can't find the equivalent way to declare it as overwrite, this leads to an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By opening [an issue on the kotlin-dsl github](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/705) I found the correct syntax:

```
tasks.replace("jar") {
    ...
}
```

However, this is the old way and does not work within a `tasks { }` block, so this issue will be further tracked [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/716)

Comment: The issue links to https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/pull/1000 which has been merged, so it should work, but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: As of Gradle 7.3.3, this doesn't seem to work. I get this error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Unit but Class<TypeVariable(T)> was expected` with an arrow pointing to the the open curly brace. If I change it to `tasks.replace("build").doLast { ... }` that particular error goes away, but then I get another error: `Cannot call Task.dependsOn(Object...) on task ':build' after task has started execution.`